# How can i upload to ftp multiple files and display it on multiple progressBars?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

I mean that if i give a List for exmaple of 30 files to upload it will open 30 slots of uploading will upload all the files in real time so i will see 30 progressBars and it will upload all the files paralel.

In form1 designer i have already one progressBar.

This is the class code for the ftp upload:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace FTP_ProgressBar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The FtpProgress class is derived from background worker, so it has the built-in functions of 
    /// run, report progress, and completed. 
    /// It only does upload, as a demonstration of how to transfer a file by FTP and report the progress. 
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FtpProgress : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public FtpProgress()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public FtpProgress(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FtpProgress_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            FtpSettings f = e.Argument as FtpSettings;
            // set up the host string to request.  this includes the target folder and the target file name (based on the source filename)
            string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", f.Host, f.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : f.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(f.SourceFile));
            if(!UploadPath.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadPath);
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = f.Passive;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            long FileSize = new FileInfo(f.SourceFile).Length;
            string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize); // e.g. "2.4 Gb" instead of 240000000000000 bytes etc...            
            int ChunkSize = 4096, NumRetries = 0, MaxRetries = 50;
            long SentBytes = 0;
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];    // this buffer stores each chunk, for sending to the web service via MTOM
            using(Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using(FileStream fs = File.Open(f.SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    int BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);  // read the first chunk in the buffer
                    // send the chunks to the web service one by one, until FileStream.Read() returns 0, meaning the entire file has been read.
                    while(BytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if(bw.CancellationPending)
                                return;

                            // send this chunk to the server.  it is sent as a byte[] parameter, but the client and server have been configured to encode byte[] using MTOM. 
                            requestStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead);

                            // sentBytes is only updated AFTER a successful send of the bytes. so it would be possible to build in 'retry' code, to resume the upload from the current SentBytes position if AppendChunk fails.
                            SentBytes += BytesRead;

                            // update the user interface
                            string SummaryText = String.Format("Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(SentBytes), FileSizeDescription);
                            bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)SentBytes / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                            if(NumRetries++ < MaxRetries)
                            {
                                // rewind the filestream and keep trying
                                fs.Position -= BytesRead;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception(String.Format("Error occurred during upload, too many retries. \n{0}", ex.ToString()));
                            }
                        }
                        BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);  // read the next chunk (if it exists) into the buffer.  the while loop will terminate if there is nothing left to read
                    }
                }
            }
            using(FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a description of a number of bytes, in appropriate units.
        /// e.g. 
        ///     passing in 1024 will return a string "1 Kb"
        ///     passing in 1230000 will return "1.23 Mb"
        /// Megabytes and Gigabytes are formatted to 2 decimal places.
        /// Kilobytes are rounded to whole numbers.
        /// If the rounding results in 0 Kb, "1 Kb" is returned, because Windows behaves like this also.
        /// </summary>
        public static string GetFileSize(long numBytes)
        {
            string fileSize = "";

            if(numBytes > 1073741824)
                fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.00} Gb", (double)numBytes / 1073741824);
            else if(numBytes > 1048576)
                fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.00} Mb", (double)numBytes / 1048576);
            else
                fileSize = String.Format("{0:0} Kb", (double)numBytes / 1024);

            if(fileSize == "0 Kb")
                fileSize = "1 Kb";  // min.                         
            return fileSize;
        }
    }

    public class FtpSettings
    {
        public string Host, Username, Password, TargetFolder, SourceFile;
        public bool Passive;
        public int Port = 21;
    }
}
```

And in form1: Upload button click event:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // the upload button is also used as a cancel button, depending on the state of the FtpProgress thread
            if(this.ftpProgress1.IsBusy)
            {
                this.ftpProgress1.CancelAsync();
                this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
            }
            else
            {
                // create a new FtpSettings class to store all the paramaters for the FtpProgress thread
                FtpSettings f = new FtpSettings();
                f.Host = this.txtHost.Text;
                f.Username = this.txtUsername.Text;
                f.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;
                f.TargetFolder = this.txtDir.Text;
                f.SourceFile = this.txtUploadFile.Text;
                f.Passive = this.chkPassive.Checked;
                try
                {
                    f.Port = Int32.Parse(this.txtPort.Text);
                }
                catch { }
                this.toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
                this.ftpProgress1.RunWorkerAsync(f);
                this.btnUpload.Text = "Cancel";
            }
        }
```

Backgorundworker progresschanged:

```
private void ftpProgress1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();   // the message will be something like: 45 Kb / 102.12 Mb
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Value = Math.Min(this.toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum, e.ProgressPercentage);      
        }
```

And completed event:

```
private void ftpProgress1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Error != null)
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString(), "FTP error");
            else if(e.Cancelled)
                this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Upload Cancelled";
            else
                this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Upload Complete";
            this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = false;
        }
```

There are in form1 designer some textboxes that i enter password user name ftp address and file to upload.

This is the file browser for uploading:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
                this.txtUploadFile.Text = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
```

Now instead one single file i want to be able to select multiple files and if i selected more then one file then it will upload the number of selected file at once paralel in real time.
If i selected 2 files it will create another new progressBar and will display on the two progressBars the files upload.

If i will select 34 files it will create 34 progressBars and will display on them the uploading progress.

Answer (score 0):

When you browse multiple files at a time, the action takes place only once. i.e; all the files selected will reach the location(Server) which you have specified. So, that is the reason you are able to see only one progress bar.

If you need multiple progress bars, you should try placing multiple buttons for selecting each file through each button.